# How to translate a JQuery function value in Javascript to ScalaJS (scalajs-jquery)

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui, scala.js

In my ScalaJS project I use [Semantic-UI](https://semantic-ui.com) with [scala-js-jquery](https://github.com/sjrd/scala-js-jquery)

I use this to monkey patch JQuery:

```
  // Monkey patching JQuery
  @js.native
  trait SemanticJQuery extends JQuery {
    def dropdown(params: js.Any*): SemanticJQuery = js.native
    def popup(params: js.Any*): SemanticJQuery = js.native
    // and more
  }

  // Monkey patching JQuery with implicit conversion
  implicit def jq2semantic(jq: JQuery): SemanticJQuery = jq.asInstanceOf[SemanticJQuery]
```

For example `$('select.dropdown').dropdown();`

translates to `jQuery(".ui.dropdown").dropdown(js.Dynamic.literal(on = "hover"))`.

My problem now is how to translate this:

```
// custom form validation rule
$.fn.form.settings.rules.adminLevel = function(value, adminLevel) {
  return (window.user.adminLevel &gt;= adminLevel)
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS snippet

```
// custom form validation rule
$.fn.form.settings.rules.adminLevel = function(value, adminLevel) {
  return (window.user.adminLevel >= adminLevel)
};
```

straightforwardly translates to

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic.{global => g}

// custom form validation rule
g.$.fn.form.settings.rules.adminLevel = { (value: js.Dynamic, adminLevel: js.Dynamic) =>
  g.window.user.adminLevel <= adminLevel
}
```

You could do something nicer with static types if you have some to represent those structures, but that's basically it if you're satisfied with a dynamically typed solution.